# Burn the [cart] tag

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

Should we burn the [cart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cart) tag?

I don't think it adds any value - it doesn't discuss a technology, it discusses an implementation of one.

Comment: Pun suggestion: Do we really need to go [shopping] for new [cart]s?

Comment: Came across this tag today and was about to write up my own request.. glad to see we've made headway in the past two years /s

Comment: I'd suggest making [cart] a synonym for [shopping-cart] and then proceed on one burninate-request

Comment: @VadimKotov does anyone have enough to make one?

Comment: @DanielA.White lets hope it will catch someone's (or even mods) attention

Comment: Went ahead and made this request specifically about [cart]. We're doing a joint burn of [shopping and shop](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404174/should-we-burninate-the-shopping-and-shop-tags?noredirect=1&lq=1); cart is too big to make the cut, and there's a substantial overlap in burn requests here. Will revisit later:tm: for a long overdue burnination

Comment: What about [tag:shopping-cart]?

Comment: @Laurel [different request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/313944/6296561)

Comment: *[Put the burn before the \[cart\]](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/put_the_cart_before_the_horse#Verb)*

Answer (score 3):

I'm adding this answer, since this burnination request seems to be a bit lost in time. As @Zoe pointed out [shopping and shop are gone](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404174/the-shopping-and-shop-tags-have-been-burninated?noredirect=1&lq=1), now let's have a re-look at this:

**Yes we should burn the [cart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cart) tag:**

**1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

- No, it is well ambiguous. Questions cover from database to css styling, from payment methods to how to use shopping-cart apps.

**2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

- No, due to its ambiguity.

**3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

- No.

**4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

- No.

Comment: Well there's a [shopping-cart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shopping-cart) tag that seems more appropriate. But if you remove the tags altogether there'll be no way to distinguish between questions about the shopping-carts and questions that just mention cart or have the keyword in the code. The cart itself being an API element can be compared to a datatype like int, str that also have their own tag across languages.

Comment: @bad_coder shopping-cart [also has a burn request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313944/lets-cart-the-shopping-cart-away)