# Let's cart the [shopping-cart] away

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

I've just noticed that we have a [shopping-cart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shopping-cart) tag, I almost cried. Do we really need this tag?

Sample questions:

- [Add shopping to existing Asp.net MVCwebsite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34570321/add-shopping-to-existing-asp-net-mvcwebsite)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34593568/what-could-be-the-possible-states-of-a-shopping-cart
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34245885/how-to-search-for-shopping-cart-not-empty-in-javascript
- <strike>1,492</strike> <strike>1,493</strike> 1,494 more (last update)

Related request:

- [Burn the [cart] and [shopping] tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258834/burn-the-cart-and-shopping-tags)

Comment: I'm **sold** on this idea.

Comment: Just had to think of [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lt0jdprQbH8).

Comment: @honk Well, the process I'm requesting begins @1:37.

Comment: @MarounMaroun: Yeah, your post made me remember exactly that scene :)

Comment: Burninate all the shopping carts.

Comment: I agree. We don't want to [get](https://www.google.com/patents/US5715314) [sued](https://www.google.com/patents/US5909492) over shopping cart patent infringement ;-)

Comment: [Relevant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188305/188613)

Comment: Would it be insensitive to suggest giving it to a tag without a [homescreen]?

Comment: Alternative pun option: `Check out [shopping-cart]`

Comment: Someone needs to come up with a pun including the amazing gameshow, Supermarket Sweep.

Comment: I'd suggest making [cart] a synonym for [shopping-cart] and then proceed on one burninate-request