# Why it is there so much delay in closing an off-topic question?

Tags: discussion, scope

2 days ago I flagged [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39675174/which-dress-is-looking-more-stunning) question as off-topic.

But I can still see this topic active.

Why is there so much delay in closing this kind of off-topic questions?

Comment: Other people need to vote as well; a question that only has a tag "shopping" is not going to be seen by many people. Looks like you found another tag to burn.

Comment: so how many votes it takes to delete of perform some kind of action on topic?

Comment: That is actually SPAM. Don't close vote spam, flag it. When in doubt if something is spam report it in the [SOCVR](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) room so the regulars there can help judging it. I've gone ahead and already [reported this one](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/33110048#33110048).

Comment: There are so many bad questions on SO that it's impossible to close them all unfortunately, some get through the cracks and don't receive the close-close they need.

Comment: Yes, the question was deleted, but to the close voters: that doesn't make this unable to be reproduced.

Comment: @Gimby Turns out there already is a burninate-request: [burn the cart and shopping tags](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258834/burn-the-cart-and-shopping-tags).