# The [shopping] and [shop] tags have been burninated

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

> ##### *This tag is in phase 4 of the burnination process described [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/324070). The question and comments have been cleaned to allow for on-topic discussion about the burnination of this tag. Please keep it that way.*
>
> ###### *If you want to discuss the process of burnination itself, post a new question on Meta or visit the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570).*

---

Today I came across [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65129437/product-tags-for-shopping) tagged [shopping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shopping).

After looking into the list of [the newest [shopping] questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shopping) (256 questions) it seems quite clear that the tag is unhelpful and ambiguous, questions relate to all kind of shopping-cart and e-commerce setup, programming, design, etc.

Burnination criteria are pretty much the same, as for the sister tag [shop](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361501/closing-up-shop) (194 questions), which is now nearly three years waiting for its burnination:

**1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

- Yes, it may describe the content environment, but no it is not unambiguous.

**2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

- No.

**3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

- No.

**4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

- No

So my question is, should we merge [shopping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shopping) and [shop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shop) and then burninate the two in one or should this stand as a single tag burnination request for [shopping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shopping)?

Comment: This might be a dupe to [Burn the 'cart' and 'shopping' tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258834/2821954). Not sure about the need to merge them before burninating, but looking at [the currently visible oldest question from 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/q/265431/2821954) (yuck...), this probably needs a proper clean-up first before burninating them.

Comment: @AndrewT. I've seen that post, but we have a slightly different situation here with shop and shopping, specially with the tag shop having 68 UV for burnination and being practically a synonym for shopping

Comment: I reject the idea of merging before burnination, not only is pointless, it gives cannon fodder to some users to reject the burnination at all because there are "too many questions".

Comment: @Braiam as of my question, that might be the answer, burn them separately. Anyway there are ~700 Q  with the two tags involved, if you look at the [posts containing shop page](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=5&tab=Relevance&q=%5bshop%5d), many shop tags were removed already, so the number is much less

Comment: I'm confused. Can you clarify a bit.

Comment: @Joshua, I'm looking at [posts containing shopping](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=1&tab=Relevance&q=[shopping]) and see 592 results, but hovering over the [shopping] tag, it says "181 watches, 256 questions" while  [posts containing shop](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=1&tab=Relevance&q=[shop]) shows 425 results, but hovering over the [shopping] tag, it says "111 watches, 194 questions"

Comment: Search includes all posts, questions and answers. Use is:q

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[shop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shop) and [shopping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shopping) have been *burninated*.

[image: trogdor]

Thanks to everyone who participated.

## Observations/Retag Guidance:

- There's a number of questions about various e-commerce platforms, and a chunk of these aren't about programming. These need to be closed, and not edited.
- There's a number of questions that use the shop/shopping tags as meta tags. Assuming they aren't off-topic, the tag(s) should be replaced with specific tags about the techs involved, such as the language, and if applicable, library/framework/platform (such as wordpress or a specific wordpress plugin, shopify, woocommerce, etc.)

## Progress:

The [shopping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shopping) and [shop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shop) tags are in the process of being burninated. You can help out by reviewing the questions with these tags, and...

- **editing** questions to improve the question *and* remove the tag (retag-only edits are best left to users with full edit privileges; i.e. > 2k reputation),
- **flagging/voting to close** questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based (users with < 3k reputation can help quite a bit by flagging questions for closure, which helps keep the Close Vote Review Queue full),
- **filtering** for questions with this tag in the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=shopping,shop),
- **voting** on questions with this tag,
- voting to **delete** the questions with this tag (after they have been closed, and only if the entire Q&A contains nothing of value). However, keep in mind that at the end of the burnination process all closed questions containing this tag will be deleted semi-automatically. Thus, there's rarely a need to vote to delete these questions.

Here are some quick links to get you started:

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bshopping%5D+or+%5Bshop%5D+closed%3Ano)
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bshopping%5D+or+%5Bshop%5D+closed%3Ayes)
- [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bshopping%5D+or+%5Bshop%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)
- [No Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bshopping%5D+or+%5Bshop%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)

## Track the progress of burnination

- [Coordination chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244740/burnination-hq)
- [Progress tracker](https://rodgort.sobotics.org/progress?metaQuestionId=404174)

## Remember that burnination is a *clean-up* effort!

#### Salvage whatever possible by editing and re-tagging.

We don't want to destroy value, so salvaging a post should be your first priority. If a question can be saved, please edit it. Your edit should improve *all* problems with the question *and* remove the [shopping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shopping) and/or [shop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shop) tag(s), possibly replacing it with another tag, as described above in "Observations/Retag Guidance". (Edits, specially re-tags, are best left to users with [full edit privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit))

#### Unsalvageable questions should just be flagged/voted for closure. They don't need to be retagged.

If the question is not appropriate for this site, then don't worry about removing the [shopping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shopping) and/or [shop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shop) tag(s)—just flag/vote to close the question.

At the end of the burnination process, all questions which still have the [shopping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shopping) and/or [shop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shop) tag(s) should have been closed. These will be mass-deleted, which will remove the tag from the system automatically, with minimal disruption.

#### Ask for help if you need it.

If you have any questions about specific questions you come across, or the process in general, please feel free to leave a comment on this post. You can also drop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570) for real-time advice and discussion.

Answer (score 39):

I agree with burninating this. Shopping isn't even a programming topic, doesn't help to identify something that's even sort of a programming topic or problem, and even if it did it would be [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping).

I say we burninate both tags.

Comment: We should probably create a synonym and burninate both of them at the same time. A synonym rather than a merge would also allow us to see which questions were tagged with what, but I don't think either of these tags was used in a meaningful way.